# How do I make a spatial union and then group by geometry with the SF package?

Tags: r, aggregate, r-sf

I am trying to make a spatial union between two layers of polygons (sf objects). The union is simple (using st_join) but when I want to indicate if there are several polygons of one layer for a polygon of the other layer, group them by making a mean, the package told me that FUN is deprecated.

```
  c <- st_join(a,b, join =st_intersects, mean)
```

Another alternative is to make the spatial union, and get as a result a layer with many more polygons (because they are duplicated) and then group them by the "geom" commum.
Is it possible to make an agrregation by geom? something like that...

```
c <- aggregate(c, c$geom ,mean,do_union, join = st_intersects)
```

Comment: Can you provide some example data?

Comment: `st_join(a, b) %>% aggregate(list(.$a.x), mean)` ?

Comment: Hard to understand exactly what you want without more code and data